# Define a Datatable using conditional logic

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to render a datatable, but depending on the value of some variable the content will slightly change.

Ideally I would like to do something like this, to re-use some part of the code:

```
var DT1 = $('#myTable').DataTable( {
    ajax: {
        url: 'ajax_search',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {},
        dataSrc: "",
    },
    if (value == 'X'){
    columns: [
        {"data": "fields.X1"},
        {"data": "fields.X2"},
    ],
    columnDefs: [
        { className: 'text-center', targets: [1] },
        {
            targets: [0],
            class: 'text-center',
            orderable: true,
            render: function (data, type, row) {
                var button1 = '<a href="/x_page/" target="_blank"><u>'+data+'</u></a>';
                return button1;
            }
        },
    ],
    } else{
        columns: [
        {"data": "fields.Y1"},
        {"data": "fields.Y2"},
    ],
    columnDefs: [
        { className: 'text-center', targets: [1] },
        {
            targets: [0],
            class: 'text-center',
            orderable: true,
            render: function (data, type, row) {
                var button2 = '<a href="/y_page/" target="_blank"><u>'+data+'</u></a>';
                return button2;
            }
        },
    ],
    }
    order: [
        [0, 'asc']
    ],
    "pagingType": "numbers",
    dom: 'rtp',
});
```

But it does not work.
Basically I just want to modify the `columns` and the `columnDefs` part based on some logic, the other parts will be the same in all the cases.

Is there a way to do that and reduce some code?

Right now the way I have this implemented is as follows (working, but probably not best practice):

```
if (condition1) {
  //  Entire table definition with all the code for condition1, without reusing any code
} else if (condition2) {
  //  Entire table definition with all the code for condition2, without reusing any code
} else {
  //  Entire table definition with all the code for conditionN, without reusing any code
}
```

But it seems extremely inefficient to me, isn't there a way to do it and reuse the common parts of the code?

Comment: Did you try the `columns.data` initialization option in the form of `function(row, type, set, meta)` to conditionally change the source of your column data? https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data

Comment: @cheesyMan Sounds promising but how can I hook it up with the data from the AJAX call? Could you provide an example?

Comment: I updated my answer with an updated fiddle, using `columnDefs` too. If this is still unclear to you, I can only suggest to dive a litte bit deeper into DataTables docs that are VERY well written, exhaustive and full of examples. Good Luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `function (row, type, val, meta)` syntax for the `columns.data` initialization option, the `row` argument automatically receives the AJAX data of each row.

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "columns": [
        { "data": function(row) {
            if(condition1) {
                return row.fieldX;
            } else if(condition2) {
                return row.fieldY;
            } else {
                // etc. 
            } 
          }
        }
     ] 
})
```

Anyway, you can see examples in the docs page I linked before

You can also look at this [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cheesyMan/3fy0cxur/48/) that uses both `columns` and `columnDefs`.

Comment: How about `columnDefs`? This is a partial solution isn't it?

Comment: `columnDefs` and `columns` are to some extent interchangeable initialization options. You can use `function(row, type, val, meta)` in `columnDefs.data` initialization option as well as in `columns.data` initialization option. https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs

Comment: Thanks for your answer, did some research but can't understand how to use a `columnDefs` or another based on some logical  condition. Could you provide a very basic example so that I can understand it better and accept your answer?

Comment: @Cheknov, the condition you check is related to the internal result of the AJAX call (i.e. if AJAX call produces X then print X, otherwise print Y)? Or it depends on some variable the AJAX call (and result) is independent from? In other words, you make always the same call and get always the same api results?

Comment: It's not related to the internal result of the AJAX call, that is why I'm a bit confused and I found it tricky. The `condition1...condition2...conditionN` are not related with the AJAX call at all. Thank you.

Comment: @Cheknov what doesn't work with the code in my answer? If I try it, it seems to me to be perfectly functional. See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cheesyMan/3fy0cxur/21/ and try to change `const condition = true  / const condition = false` in the javascript

Comment: That solves partially my problem since I need to render some columns based on some logic as well (like...if condition1 = true, render this cell with a <a> tag, stuff like that) and the code you provided don't have any mechanism to use `columnDefs` under certain logical constraints.